# Playing sounds in Android mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I have having some troubles with HTML5 Audio in Android Browser.
I need to play the same sound, 9 times. Which works great the first time I play them, because a make 9 sound objects. It may not be ideal but it works... atleast I thought it did.

**This is how i do it:**

```
var setSounds = function(){
    Sounds[0] = new x.Sound();
};
```

**And then I play the sound like this:**

```
       Sounds[0].play();
```

**I have tried the following**

```
        Sounds.[0].pause();
        Sounds.[0].play();
```

**And**

```
        Sound.[0].currentTime = 0;
```

I have more sounds then this just but to give you an idea. It plays all the sounds correctly the first time, but the second time I want to play all the sounds, its silent. This problem only occurs in Android browser.

*Playing all the 9 sound objects first time* - Perfect

*Replaying the 9 sound objects again* - Silent

How can i play my sound objects again? Any advice or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Did you try doing something like seek(0) before your calls to play()? I'm not sure if that's equivalent to setting currentTime=0. Also, can you turn repeat on? Does that help?

Comment: Matt - Thanks for the respons. I did try seek() now, and no change. I can't use repeat because the sounds are played on user touchevents. I got 9 boxes i want the user to click on them, but it can be 30 seconds or 2minutes between the first 9 sounds and the second 9 sounds.

Comment: Try re-initializing all the sounds after each click? after calling sounds[i].play, then call setSounds() again? It's a bit wasteful, but as long as setSounds is fast, should work...

Comment: Matt - Thanks for the response. Yeah, that works, thanks! I'm just worried how this effects the performance? This essentially makes it 18 objects, correct? And i want the user to be able do this over and over and over again..

Comment: I don't think it's too much overhead, but you should definitely test. I've added a real "answer" with an additional suggestion (just re-init the sound that was played, one-at-a-time). If it works, and your testing passes, please accept my answer!

Comment: I have yet to test it probably, but it works therefor I accept your answer and thank you very much. Merry christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest work-around is to re-initialize the sound after it's been played.

Call sound[0].play(), then call setSounds(). If you're worried about the overhead in re-creating all the sounds, you could just re-initialize the one sound:

```
Sounds[0].play();
Sounds[0] = new x.Sound();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer. It may not be the best option for me but it solves the problem. Thanks a lot